# Adding Nginx-Ingress/Certmanager as Dependency in Helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster(Azure) with nginx-ingress, certmanager and one application, and I was wondering if there's a way of making the whole system as one single package so if there's any problem with the cluster it'd be easier to spin up another one.

My main idea is to make the manual configuration of nginx-ingress and certmanager automatic, but I'm not sure how it'd included in a helm chart, if possible. If not possible, is there a way(or tool) for minimising the manual configuration of environments when spinning it up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a package of multiple helm charts here, likely as follows-

1. Helm chart of your services
2. Other dependency services helm charts (like redis, kafka etc)
3. Nginx helm chart
4. Then you can add cert-manager's helm chart which carries cluster issuer, certificate and it can either self create the TLS secret, by name mentioned by you ( or you can add your own secret)
5. Then adding the ingress rule will place things inline for you.

Just package things up in helm chart .tgz formats

Comment: Thank you very much, Tushar! I just have one more question: how can I get nginx/cert-manager charts? Is it the charts available on their repository or it's something i need to create from scratch?

Comment: both are available, you can get those from their respective github repositories