# Custom helm chart - helm dep update fails with Error: stable/nginx-ingress chart not found in repo https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

## How can I add stable/nginx-ingress as a dependency to my custom helm chart?

After trying a few different urls for the repository, I still have no luck.

Steps

1. Created a new helm chart with helm create and editing the `Chart.yaml` to be

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: acme
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 1.16.0
icon: https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

dependencies:
  - name: stable/nginx-ingress
    version: ~1.34
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

2. Executed this command `helm dep update acme`

The output is the following

`Error: stable/nginx-ingress chart not found in repo https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com`

**Note**

I have seen these Stack Overflow questions, but the answers were lacking explanation:

- [Helm V3 - Cannot find the official repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970255/helm-v3-cannot-find-the-official-repo)
- [Adding Nginx-Ingress/Certmanager as Dependency in Helm Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454550/adding-nginx-ingress-certmanager-as-dependency-in-helm-charts)

This question is not intended to be a duplicate. I'm not using Azure and I am using Helm 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated chart for helm3 is [ready to use](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm).

> ```
> helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
> helm install my-release ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
> ```

---

#### Original

The [nginx-ingress chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx) is not published there yet. The progress is being tracked in [kubernetes/ingress-nginx#5161](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5161).

If you want to use the old chart you will need either a copy of the chart locally, or a version of the chart published to your own repo. For the local file dependency, get a copy of the current chart:

```
git clone https://github.com/helm/charts.git
cp -r charts/stable/nginx-ingress /path/to/acmes-parent-dir/
```

Then you can use a relative reference to the local directory:

```
dependencies:
- name: nginx-ingress
  version: "1.34"
  repository: "file://../nginx-ingress"
```

Comment: That's assuming the previous chart works with helm3 ok. I haven't actually tried to manage nginx-ingress with helm3 yet.

Comment: Tremendously helpful, thanks. If you post an answer in the other thread I will award you the 50 reputation points for the bounty I started because the solution will likely work for their case as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454550/adding-nginx-ingress-certmanager-as-dependency-in-helm-charts

Comment: No worries. The other question needs a bit more detail than this, if I get a chance I'll take a look.